# HABTM Adding new associations to join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-and-belongs-to-many

How do I add multiple records to a `has_and_belongs_to_many` table between two models?

All I can figure out how to do so far is create one record, and then update that record. I want to add multiple records to the join table.

Right now I have a collection_select, but the update method only allows me to update the record, not add new records.

My best guess is to add something like `@group.workouts << workout_id` to the update method in the group controller, but I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Am I on the right track here?

I am trying to add workouts to groups and groups to workouts.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT 1:

I have a `collection_select` that allows me to add a single record to the join table, but I'm trying to figure out how to add a second, third, etc. record to the join table. My `collection_select` is:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.collection_select 'workout_ids', Workout.all, :id, :name, { :include_blank => ""} %>
</div>
```

So simply, I want to add a workout to a group, which I can do. Then I want to add another workout to that same group, then another, etc.

Comment: you are looking for has_many :through. I'm not sure if you can do this with HABTM

Comment: You can do this with HABTM. You just need a collection select, or other association selection tool.

Comment: I just updated my question. I can add a single record with a collection_select, but I'm trying to add additional records after I add the first record.

Comment: Using multiple: true option can also do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT:

The actual way to do this properly is detailed in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/arelenglish/6110438)

<s>So the answer to this is to edit the update action in the controller with this:</s>

```
workout_id = params[:group].delete(:workout_ids)

    # Adding a workout
    if workout_id
      workout = Workout.find(workout_id)
      @group.workouts << workout
    end
```

The above code creates a local variable `workout_id` that takes the parameters `:group` and `:workout_id` from within `:group` the `.delete` method removes the second parameter for updating the actual group when you change the name of the group, for example.

Then we simply push a new workout onto @group.workouts, creating a new record in the join table every time we add a new workout to the group from the collection select.

Answer (score 2):

In the console you can do like you guessed:

```
group.workouts << workout
```

or

```
workout.groups += [group_a, group_b, group_c]
```

Of the top of my head I think you'll want to pass actual objects, not just the IDs, but it may work both ways.

In a form builder should be able to use `collection_select` for this:

```
= form_for @workout do |f|
  = f.collection_select :group_id, Group.all, :id, :name, :prompt => true
```

Other tools like [Simple Form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)'s association method make this easier.

Comment: Thanks for the help! The form builder works to add a single record to the join table, but What I'm having trouble with is adding additional records to the join table. So I can assign one workout to a group, but how do I then assign a second workout to the same group instead of just updating the existing record? Does that make sense?

Comment: Select multiple in the form. CMD-click in a mac, or CNTRL-click on windows. Or make the collection select be checkboxes.

Comment: That's a good idea, but what I'm trying to do is a bit more dynamic than that. I want to be able to add records in the future without risking loosing past data.